# SwiftUI: Implement a simple timing slider

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a line slider that looks like this:

```
  Path { path in
      path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
      path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200 * (timeRemaining), y: 0))
  }
  .stroke(Color.orange, lineWidth: 4).opacity(0.5)
```

The timeRemaining will go from 2s, 1s, 0s making the line slider to decrease from right to left.  How can I change this implementation so that the slider will decrease more like this:

```
400,399,398...2,1,0
```

which will make the line slider looks smoother.

Here is the timer declaration:

```
  @State var timeRemaining = 2
  @State var timer: Timer.TimerPublisher = Timer.publish (every: 1, 
  on: .main, in: .common)
```

---

```
 .onReceive(timer) { time in
    if timeRemaining > 0 {
      timeRemaining -= 1
    }
```

I think I need to make some changes in the onReceive part.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you want to split the time range (2s) into 400 parts? Isn't it the timer you should change then?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, I am looking at how could do that in the timer part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a finer granularity and a smoother animation you simply need to scale down the update interval. Since 2 / 400 is 0.005 you should use this for your timer and your count down

```
@State var timeRemaining = 2.0 // Use Double
@State var timer: Timer.TimerPublisher = Timer.publish (every: 0.005, on: .main, in: .common)

...

.onReceive(timer) { time in
if timeRemaining > 0 {
  timeRemaining -= 0.005
}
```

Comment: but on every 1s, I need to refresh the page to show a different set of data, this will refresh the page every 0.005s

Comment: @DarylWong That wasn't part of the question but you can simply have another else condition or a separate variable or maybe  use on timer for the animation and one timer for the refresh

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean, I need another condition.